# CustomValidator　が動作しない

Tags: asp.net

asp.net　について質問です

CustomValidator　を利用したところ、コントロールまでデバックができず
動作されておりません

☆ビュー

```
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox18" runat="server" Text="" ></asp:TextBox>
    <br />       
    <asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server"
         ErrorMessage="asp.netという文字が入っていない" ControlToValidate="TextBox18" OnServerValidate="CustomValidator1_ServerValidate"></asp:CustomValidator><br />
    <asp:Button ID="Button5" runat="server" Text="送信" />
```

☆コントロール

```
   protected void CustomValidator1_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
    {
        var text = args.Value;
        if(text.IndexOf("asp.net")>=0)
        {
            args.IsValid = true;
        }
        else
        {
            args.IsValid = false;
        }
    }
```

上記で何か不備はありますでしょうか。ご教授お願いいたします＞＜

Comment: https://teratail.com/questions/24150　マルチポスト

Answer (score 1):

不備はありません。

上記ソースにてデバッグしてみましたが、送信ボタン押下後に
きちんとCustomValidator1_ServerValidateが呼び出されます。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
原因不明なのですが、私も１日あけてから再度動かしてみたところ
なぜか動作しました。＞＜